# Category sitemap doesn't respect the menu position

Tags: magento-1.9, category, sitemaps

I have a problem with my category sitemap.

Like you can see here : http://bizpro.ch/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/ the category list doesn't respect the menu position.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Are you using a module for your sitemap generation? In that case you'll need to fix that in the modules source

Comment: No,I d'ont use any module.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Seo_Sitemap_Category` class from your own module (more on that here: http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

And set the order yourself

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Catalog_Seo_Sitemap_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Seo_Sitemap_Category
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

        // here I've edited the first argument to be `position` instead of default `name`
        $collection = $helper->getStoreCategories('position', true, false);
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this solution but nothing changed.

Comment: @banu are you sure your rewrite class is used? (just to be sure)

Comment: I think that it's ok but to be sur I modified directly Mage/Catalog/Seo/Sitemap/Category.php but nothing changed.(I have a backup of course)

Comment: @banu I'll test this tomorrow  and report back

Comment: @banu can you print the collection query? Should be `var_dump((string)$collection->getSelect());`

Comment: This must be done in tree.phtml?

Comment: Or in the class after `$collection = $helper->getStoreCategories(...`

Comment: I added in the class but nothing appears.Where this collection query must be printed?

Comment: @banu if nothing is printed I highly doubt that class is ever touched. are you sure you're working with cache off on the right file / environment?

Comment: Now it's ok with var_dump((string)$_items->getSelect());You can find the printed query here :  http://bizpro.ch/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/

Comment: hm, not sure where the `ORDER BY main_table.path ` comes from. By the way, set your `robots` meta tag to `noindex,nofollow` before debugging info like this get indexed :)

Comment: Thanks,do you have any solution?

Comment: @banu not right away. I'll think about it. Give me a few days

Comment: Thanks,you think it is a good idea to use an extension?

Comment: @banu might be. I use http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/creare-html-sitemap-for-seo.html myself. but having a specific order might just require you to write it yourself

Comment: You said I must set my robots meta tag to noindex, nofollow.For google the links order in sitemap.xml is important?